# How do I write data to stdin of child_process in Firefox Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The [`child_process` Add-on SDK docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) state that the `child_process` module implements [the node.js child_process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). So, I'm trying to spawn a sub-process and write data to it as described in [the node.js docs section covering the `spawn` method](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
var child_process = require("sdk/system/child_process");

var doiuse = child_process.spawn("/usr/local/bin/doiuse");
doiuse.stdin.write(data);
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: doiuse.stdin.write is not a function
```

So, how do I write to a child process in the Firefox Add-on SDK?

Answer (score 1):

In the [#jetpack IRC channel](http://irc://irc.mozilla.org/#jetpack), it was suggested to use code like [the child_process tests](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/b952add4eb48d2a977374b91c9ab76e22ab41a3d/test/test-child_process.js#L396-L447). So, I got it working with:

```
const { emit } = require('sdk/event/core');
const { spawn } = require('sdk/system/child_process');

var proc = spawn("/bin/cat");

emit(proc.stdin, 'data', "Hello from Add-on code");
emit(proc.stdin, 'end');
```

Comment: Great initive to continue seeking help after posting this answer. And great of you to share to benefit everyone else! Thanks!